# popup don't worked currently in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I want when mouse hover on the images in my website popup run .I wrote this codes.

```
.popupbigimg:hover , .popup:hover  ,.divbigimg:hover {
    z-index: 1000;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 3px solid #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px rgba(212, 209, 209, 0.4);
    -ms-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px rgba(212, 209, 209, 0.4);
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px rgba(212, 209, 209, 0.4);

    -moz-transform: scale(1.03);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.03);
    -o-transform: scale(1.03);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.03);
    transform: scale(1.03);

    -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease;
    -moz-transition: all 500ms ease;
    -ms-transition: all 500ms ease;
    -o-transition: all 500ms ease;
    transition: all 500ms ease;
    display: table;

}
```

This codes run currently in ff but in chrome no.Please see this image:
[image]

When popup running another elements display on the image.You can see my website in this [link](http://hmahdavi.zgig.ir/%D9%86%D9%85%D9%88%D9%86%D9%87%20%DA%A9%D8%A7%D8%B102/bamilo_Demo/Index.html).
Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a high `z-index` to `#colman2` resolved this for me.